# Подключение OpenOffice к Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, open-office

При создании подключения он требует указать: Файл баз данных (обзор) и указать зарегистрированное название. Из справки: "Укажите путь и имя файла базы данных. Имя файла должно иметь расширение *.odb.". Где мне его взять на локальной машине? И вообще правильно ли я делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, порядок действий таков: в OpenOffice Base необходимо создать базу данных, связанную нужными таблицами через драйвера java или odbc с базой PostgreSQL, а затем указывать её в качестве источника.